# Exchange 2007 SCR and Failover clustering?

Tags: exchange-2007

I'm currently wanting to implement a backup Exchange server, and from what i read it sounds like SCR is the way to go.  I currently have one Exchange 2007 server, pretty small and nothing special going on.  I built another server and set the drives the same (as was recommended on technet).  Online i see several sites saying, "all you need to do is this" run these commands:

Enable-StorageGroupCopy -Identity  
-StandbyMachine  -ReplayLagTime 0.1:0:0

Suspend-StorageGroupCopy -Identity  
-StandbyMachine

Update-StorageGroupCopy -Identity  
-StandbyMachine

But my question is even more basic i guess...  I logon to the secondary server, and obviously Exchange isn't on there so i assume i'd need to install it first before i can set it as a passive/backup server.  I run the install but when i select Passive Clustered Mailbox Role it informs me it needs to be setup as a Clustered Server first (which makes sense).  But i'm wondering, do i need to set up two servers in a cluster to make this work?  I'm not wanting real-time failover, just the SCR ability to turn the passive server into the active server in response to a disaster.  Would i just need to install Exchange on the second server as if it were the only one in the domain (Mailbox Role) and then once done, run the above commands?  Any help explaining this woudl be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install Exchange as a Clustered server. SCR does not depend on clustering. In fact, if you do setup a cluster, you're going to require more servers. You want to install Exchange on the second server using a Typical installation with Mailbox, Hub Transport, and CAS roles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Being that my current Exchange server is in production, i assume by installing the second one it's not going to interfere with the primary server, right? Just making sure i'm not going to aggravate a couple hundred people in the middle of the day. :) Thanks!

Comment: No just installing Exchange on a second server isn't going to interfere with the primary server. I would schedule some maintenance time during the initial replication though as that could slow performance for your users.